# Need to wait on specific column state change in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check for the status change of a certain column in the table 
I can do it using while loop, where i can get the column value and check the value and break from the loop if value is changed.
i am using SQL server 2008. 
is there a better way?

Here is the sample sql query

```
   declare @status int = 1

   select @status = status from MyTable with (nolock) where Id = 100034

   while @status <> 3
   begin
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:01'
      select @status = status from MyTable with (nolock) where Id = 100034
   end
```

Comment: Can you show your query you have written so far ?

Comment: You could use a trigger, see here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2911/working-with-triggers/

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and the results you want.  Your description is rather vague for someone not familiar with what you are doing or trying to do.

Comment: What do you need to do when you "see" this change?

Comment: added sample sql query used by me

Comment: The best way is a Trigger but it depends if what you want to do after see this value is inside SQL Server. If you need to do something outside (for instance refresh an screen of your app) the only option is a timer, with a query to the DB inside to check that value.

Comment: @ericpap it's not the only option, query notifications would be another. Though I doubt they fire until the change is committed. So not equivalent to `nolock`

Comment: is it good to do wait inside the SQL or do the sleep in my application and make connection after every 5 minutes and check the status?

Comment: You still haven't told us what happens when the condition is met.

Comment: when the condition is met, i exit from my application with success.

Comment: Do you have to check for time out? what kind of application and framework are you using?

Comment: @Horaciux, i am not using this approach now, instead moved the logic to application layer i.e. in C++

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to use a trigger instead of an stored procedure? This is exactly, what are triggers for.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reactOnStatus3
ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
  IF Status = 3
     EXEC DoTheMagicStoredProcedure;
END;
```